# Downgrade PHP5.5.1 to 5.4.*

Tags: php, centos, downgrade

I've got a Centos 6 server (x64) with PHP 5.5.1 running on it. 
But I would like to downgrade to 5.4.*.

I already tried this command

```
yum downgrade php php-common php-cli
```

But I'm receiving this error: http://pastie.org/8325539

Thanks in advance

** SOLUTION **

```
yum erase php php-pear php-mysql php-cli php-common
```

Comment: rpm -qa |grep php and then remove all the php current packages by yum remove php or rpm -e. Then try installing php-5.4 it shall work

Comment: So, when I do this command: 'rpm -qa |grep php', I'm getting this list of packages: http://pastie.org/private/u4atoji5zakrqxatg8ikcq. I'll have to remove them all before I can install PHP 5.4? Because the command: 'yum remove php' didn't do the trick and 'rmp -e' needs a extra parameter. Sorry, I'm just learning how to work with Centos.

Comment: Ok, I just found an easy way, I added the solution to my question. Now it removes all PHP and his packages

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should completely remove 5.5.x and then install 5.4.x

About the error, those are due to the dependencies which may be affected by the downgrade; like gd and mbcrypt.